# Timer task repite el activity entero y no solo los métodos dentro de el

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

El problema es el siguiente, estoy usando un timer task y dentro tengo varios métodos, lo que pasa es que cada vez que entra en el timer task es como si se reiniciara el activity y las variables vuelven a su valor de inicio y no se el porque ocurre esto.
El código es demasiado largo, por lo que pondré la parte de la creación, y cuando lo activo.
También querria saber si es posible poder elegir cuando se repita y cuando no.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        AsyncHttpClient clienteTurno = new AsyncHttpClient();
                        RequestParams rpTurno = new RequestParams();
                        rpTurno.put("IdPartida", IdPartida);
                        rpTurno.put("IdUsuario", IdUsuario);


                        clienteTurno.get(urlTurno, rpTurno, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                                if (statusCode == 200) {
                                    String respuesta = response.toString();
                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    ComprobarTurno turno = gson.fromJson(respuesta, ComprobarTurno.class);

                                    int res = turno.getSuccess();

                                    //Si es correcta

                                        turnoJugador = turno.getPosicion();
                                        turnoActual = turno.getTurno();
                                        valorRecibidoReal = turno.getValorRecibidoReal();
                                        valorRecibido = turno.getValorRecibido();



                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

    /*

    new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
  }
    }, 2500);
     */
                        Log.d("turno", turnoActual);
                        Log.d("turno", turnoJugador);
                        Log.d("valor", valorRecibido);


                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PartidaOnlineActivity.this);
                                if (turnoActual.equalsIgnoreCase(turnoJugador)) {
```

AQUI IRIAN TODOS LOS MÉTODOS

```
} else {
                                    if (dialogo == false) {
                                        progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                        progressDialog.setMessage("Esperando que el otro jugador tire...");
                                        progressDialog.show();
                                        dialogo = true;

                                    }
                                }


                            }
                        }, 2500);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };


        timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```